# Project variables in PCA plot in Python

Tags: python, r, pca

After performing a PCA analysis in R we can do:

```
ggbiplot(pca, choices=1:2, groups=factor(row.names(df_t)))
```

That will plot the data in the 2 PC space, and the direction and weight of the variables in such space as vectors (with different length and direction).

In Python I can plot the data in the 2 PC space, and I can get the weights of the variables, but how do I know the direction.

In other words, how could I plot the variable contribution to both PC (weight and direction) in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by weight and direction here? The principal components are linear combinations of your original predictors. By weight, do you mean the coefficient of the original features in the principal component? What does direction mean here?

Comment: By direction and weight I mean the data used to plot the arrows here for example: http://www.sthda.com/sthda/RDoc/figure/factor-analysis/pca-contribution-factominer-variable-cos2-factoextra-data-mining-1.png

Comment: I'm not sure that plot means anything to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of any pre-made implementation of this kind of plot, but it can be created using `matplotlib.pyplot.quiver`. Here's an example I quickly put together. You can use this as a basis to create a nice plot that works well for your data.

---

#### Example Data

This generates some example data. It is reused from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114760/how-to-plot-the-confusion-similarity-matrix-of-a-k-mean-algorithm/45133875#45133875).

```
# User input
n_samples  = 100
n_features =   5

# Prep
data  = np.empty((n_samples,n_features))
np.random.seed(42)

# Generate
for i,mu in enumerate(np.random.choice([0,1,2,3], n_samples, replace=True)):
    data[i,:] = np.random.normal(loc=mu, scale=1.5, size=n_features)
```

---

#### PCA

```
pca = PCA().fit(data)
```

---

#### Variables Factor Map

Here we go:

```
# Get the PCA components (loadings)
PCs = pca.components_

# Use quiver to generate the basic plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.quiver(np.zeros(PCs.shape[1]), np.zeros(PCs.shape[1]),
           PCs[0,:], PCs[1,:], 
           angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)

# Add labels based on feature names (here just numbers)
feature_names = np.arange(PCs.shape[1])
for i,j,z in zip(PCs[1,:]+0.02, PCs[0,:]+0.02, feature_names):
    plt.text(j, i, z, ha='center', va='center')

# Add unit circle
circle = plt.Circle((0,0), 1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='b')
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)

# Ensure correct aspect ratio and axis limits
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim([-1.0,1.0])
plt.ylim([-1.0,1.0])

# Label axes
plt.xlabel('PC 0')
plt.ylabel('PC 1')

# Done
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

#### Being Uncertain

I struggled a bit with the scaling of the arrows. Please make sure they correctly reflect the loadings for your data. A quick check of whether `feature 4` really correlates strongly with `PC 1` (as this example would suggest) looks promising:

```
data_pca = pca.transform(data)
plt.scatter(data_pca[:,1], data[:,4])
plt.xlabel('PC 2') and plt.ylabel('feature 4')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to WhoIsJack for the earlier answer.

I adapted there code to a function below that takes in a fitted PCA object and the data it was based on. It produces the figure similar to above, but I substituted out real column names for the column index, and then pruned it to only show a certain number of contributing columns.

```
def plot_pca_vis(pca, df: pd.DataFrame, pc_x: int = 0, pc_y: int = 1, num_dims: int = 5):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148539/project-variables-in-pca-plot-in-python
    Adapted into function by Tim Cashion
    """
    # Get the PCA components (loadings)
    PCs = pca.components_

    PC_x_index = PCs[pc_x, : ].argsort()[-num_dims:][::-1]
    PC_y_index = PCs[pc_y, : ].argsort()[-num_dims:][::-1]
    combined_index = set(list(PC_x_index) + list(PC_y_index))
    PCs = PCs[:, list(combined_index)]
    # Use quiver to generate the basic plot
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.quiver(np.zeros(PCs.shape[1]), np.zeros(PCs.shape[1]),
            PCs[pc_x,:], PCs[pc_y,:], 
            angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)

    # Add labels based on feature names (here just numbers)
    feature_names = df.columns
    for i,j,z in zip(PCs[pc_y,:]+0.02, PCs[pc_x,:]+0.02, feature_names):
        plt.text(j, i, z, ha='center', va='center')

    # Add unit circle
    circle = plt.Circle((0,0), 1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='b')
    plt.gca().add_artist(circle)

    # Ensure correct aspect ratio and axis limits
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.xlim([-1.0,1.0])
    plt.ylim([-1.0,1.0])

    # Label axes
    plt.xlabel('PC ' + str(pc_x))
    plt.ylabel('PC ' + str(pc_y))
    # Done
    plt.show()
```

Hope this helps someone!